# Encoding included in .append? Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf

I am a complete beginner when it comes to Python, and currently getting closer towards the end of LPTHW. Now, in exercise 41, there is a line of code in a for-loop that I do not quite get.

I have searched online to the best of my abilities, but as I am still learning, I was not completely sure how to even search for this.

To clarify:

- WORD_URL is just a series of words.
- WORDS is an empty list.

---

This is the loop:

```
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(str(word.strip(), encoding="utf-8"))
```

---

Now what I do not really understand is what this `WORDS.append(str(word.strip(), encoding='utf-8')` does. Why is `encoding="utf-8"` included, and what does it to in this context? I suspect the use of `str` here is connected to this some way, but not completely sure. Would it not be possible to simply just have it like this:

```
.append(word.strip())?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look carefully at the parentheses: encoding is a parameter to `str`, not `append`.

Comment: As @DanielRoseman pointed out, `encoding` is for `str`, not `append`. With that knowledge, check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet

```
WORDS.append(str(word.strip(), encoding='utf-8'))
```

removes the whitespace from word, and coverts word to a utf-8 encoded string.
The str function takes care of the encoding.

The code you provided

```
WORDS.append(word.strip())
```

would place the variable word, with no whitespace at the end of the list WORDS.
The difference being that no encoding is specified, so the variable word will be placed at the end of WORDS in whatever encoding the variable word currently is. In the first example, all strings placed in WORDS will be utf-8 encoded.